# How to work with RelativeLayout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout with many edittexts and buttons and textviews, and I arranged them in 4 LinearLayouts, as child of a RelativeLayout. The problem is that if I use a different size of screen, the LinearLayouts are not at the same place where I put them, and I can't make it work. How to deal with this problem? This are the codes for the **medii.xml** file where I have them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mediib" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="255dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/nota2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/nota"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bb" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bbc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginRight="33dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/nota2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/nota"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/nota2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/teze"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bb" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bbc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/nota2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/nota"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button06"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bb" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button05"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bbc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText04"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/nota2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/nota"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button04"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bb" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bbc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want: I want to keep the arrangment I make on all sizes of screens.

How the layout should look:

[image]

Comment: "...LinearLayouts are not at the same place where I put them..." What are you intending to get? Be specific.

Comment: I want to have the arrangment I make on all sizes of screens.

Comment: Still not clear, you make us guess. A picture is normally provided. I assume some of your EditTexts, Buttons and TextView go behind the screen, which is ok, taking into consideration the amount of layouts oriented vertically. Try to wrap all LinearLayouts with ScrollView (as an option).

Comment: please let me know whats the  problem you are facing right now. what i understand is that you are facing issue related to  multiple screen support issue . which i explain in following question check this out .http://stackoverflow.com/a/22836383/3484813

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. My suggestion is to stay away from "magical" margin and padding numbers such as 255 dp and such. Try centering elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mediib"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="255dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/nota2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/nota"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bb" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bbc" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="33dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/nota2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/nota"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/nota2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/teze"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bb" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bbc" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText03"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/nota2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/nota"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button06"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bb" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button05"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bbc" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText04"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/nota2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/nota"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button04"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bb" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button03"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bbc" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: I eddited it quite a bit removed the pictures and strings so I can see it in my eclipse you might want to add those back. I got a very similar look to what you are trying to achieve in the picture. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="asd" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asd" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asd" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="asd" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="asd" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asd" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asd" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="asd" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button06"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asd" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button05"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asd" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText04"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="asd" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button04"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asd" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asd" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Its not in the EXACT same position because different phones have different resolutions. Like I said before, try using centering of buttons instead of padding and margin with random magical numbers to get best result on different resolutions

Comment: I know it can't be exactly, but it's not even good, I mean, some items are not on the layout, and you can't use them... and about centering, I used this method for others layouts where I could have it done, but here, the layout should look like in the picture, if I could center them, I wouldn't have requested for help. Thanks !